How long do Yanfei's Scarlet Seals's last?
I'm deciding on which Liyue 4-star from the Lantern Rite event to get for a Speed-focused Party, and not sure between Gaming as a Chiori that needs planning around, or Yanfei as a Catalyst and a unique ability, assuming her Scarlet Seals generated by attacking enemies, reduces Sprinting Stamina as well as other kinds.
But the Wiki doesn't indicate how long Yanfei's Seals last, just that making a new one extends their lifetime, and they go away if I switch Yanfei out.
So, how long does Yanfei's Scarlet Seals's last, if I don't consume them early somehow?

both theorycraft guides say 10 seconds ("Each Normal Attack hit grants Yanfei a Scarlet Seal for 10s") but I can't doublecheck this info right now
